# LEDs don't trigger on CPU activity

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-modules, arm64

I'm trying to set some triggers for the LEDs on an embedded board (Rock960). They work with `heartbeat` and `mmc1` (main drive) and `none` of course, but I haven't been able to get any of the `cpu<i>` triggers to work.

Is there a way of checking if anything is actually sending a trigger? Even under full load (e.g. a `make -j6` job, nothing lights up).

```
# Disk activity works as does rfkill1 (wifi)
echo mmc1 >/sys/class/leds/rock960\:green\:user0/trigger

# None of these seem to do anything
echo cpu0 >/sys/class/leds/rock960\:green\:user1/trigger
echo cpu1 >/sys/class/leds/rock960\:green\:user2/trigger
echo cpu2 >/sys/class/leds/rock960\:green\:user3/trigger
```

According to my config, I have the modules compiled in:

```
# LED Triggers
CONFIG_LEDS_TRIGGERS=y
CONFIG_LEDS_TRIGGER_TIMER=y
CONFIG_LEDS_TRIGGER_ONESHOT=y
CONFIG_LEDS_TRIGGER_HEARTBEAT=y
CONFIG_LEDS_TRIGGER_BACKLIGHT=y
CONFIG_LEDS_TRIGGER_CPU=y
CONFIG_LEDS_TRIGGER_GPIO=y
CONFIG_LEDS_TRIGGER_DEFAULT_ON=y
```

Available triggers:

```
none rc-feedback kbd-scrolllock kbd-numlock kbd-capslock kbd-kanalock kbd-shiftlock kbd-altgrlock kbd-ctrllock kbd-altlock kbd-shiftllock kbd-shiftrlock kbd-ctrlllock kbd-ctrlrlock mmc0 [mmc1] timer oneshot heartbeat backlight gpio cpu0 cpu1 cpu2 cpu3 cpu4 cpu5 default-on rfkill0 mmc2 rfkill1 rfkill2
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe the most appropriate trigger for that case would be the `activity`, that aims at showing the CPU activity system-wise. Here is the description of it:

> This allows LEDs to be controlled by an immediate CPU usage. The flash
> frequency and duty cycle varies from faint flashes to intense
> brightness depending on the instant CPU load

For that you need to enable it at the kernel: `CONFIG_LEDS_TRIGGER_ACTIVITY=y` but most modern distributions have it by default.

from https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/LEDS_TRIGGER_ACTIVITY.html

Comment: Thanks for this - I've upvoted, but I haven't had a chance to test this yet. Sounds reasonable though!